# Why aren't Annie and Jack together in Speed 2?

Tags: speed-2-cruise-control

In [Speed 2: Cruse Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_2:_Cruise_Control) how do they explain away why Annie (Sandra Bullock's character) isn't with Jack (Keanu Reeves's character)? It doesn't explain on Wikipedia.

Comment: Because Reeves didn't sign the contract?

Comment: There is also this line in the first movie Jack: "I have to warn you, I've heard relationships based on intense experiences never work."

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question.  Jack and Annie's relationship was one of the main points in the first movie.  Fans would be curious on why they are not together anymore.  I know that I was when I watched the sequel.

Comment: @DustinDavis  Good point!  That would have been cool if they would have referenced that in the sequel.

Comment: @steelersquirrel - Catja's answer below is correct.  Jack isn't mentioned by name, but Annie does talk about how her ex was a cop and she doesn't date cops anymore.

Comment: @Tim Okay.  It's been a while since I have seen the movie.  I know that relationships fail, but it would have been nice for the fans to get an explanation on what happened with Jack and Annie.  I guess that her mentioning that she doesn't date cops anymore was all that they wanted to tell us :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel - she actually says more than that - there's stuff about him buying her pepper spray, her thinking it's perfume, a resultant trip to the emergency room... all this while she's trying to pass a driving test (and failing).  It's an Annie-point-of-view explanation.  If you search, you can find quotes about it all.

Comment: @Tim Oh, really?  Cool!  Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel http://www.the-editing-room.com/speed2.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Honestly... because Keanu Reeves said no.

From an interview on Jimmy Kimmel Live (quoted on [Den of Geek](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/speed/37285/speed-2-why-keanu-reeves-turned-it-down)):

> "I loved working with Jan de Bont and Sandra, of course. It was just a situation in life where I got the script and I read the script and I was like 'ugggghhh’. It was about a cruise ship and I was thinking, 'a bus, a cruise ship… Speed, bus, but then a cruise ship is even slower than a bus and I was like, ‘I love you guys but I just can’t do it".

As a note, Bullock also initially tried to pass on the film [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_2:_Cruise_Control#Casting) but was convinced to do it with the promise of getting another project (*Hope Floats*) into production.

A little bit further down in the article it explains the in-universe reason:

> After Reeves declined to appear in Speed 2, the screenplay was rewritten to remove his character from the story, which De Bont wanted to deal with early in the film. **His absence is explained in the first scene**, where Annie talks about how her relationship with Jack did not work out, and mentions her current relationship with Alex (Patric), before his character is introduced in the film.

So, if you did opt to rewatch the film, you wouldn't have to watch much of it.

Comment: Nooo!!! Fastest gun in the west!

Comment: Haha brilliant still without knowing it was covered so quickly it wasn't worth the risk,cheers

Answer (score 2):

It's explained at the end of *Speed*!

I can't remember the quote, but Jack says that relationships based on traumatic situations never last!

Annie does come back by saying that it'll be based on sex instead, but Jack's point still stands...